# Is there any way to compile C++ code by pressing f5 or any other key in VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

Is there any shortcut key in vscode to compile C++ code , like vim or atom has f5 ? Press the key and you have a black dialog window . I use vscode for competitive programming and I compile code using "g++" syntax on command prompt . Any method faster than this will work .

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Comment: Could be useful: [Execute a bat file on keypress in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849230/2752075)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the extension called "Code Runner". To do that :

1. Click on the four squares with one square not align icon on the left.
2. Type "Code Runner", find the extension and install it.
3. Also install the "C/C++" extension.
4. When both extensions are installed, to compile and run, press Ctrl + Alt + n.

Small tip :
If you want to use VS Code for competitive programming, you might want to change where the code runs to the terminal. As default, the c++ code will get executed in the "output" window but that is a output-only window, so you will not be able to test inputs. To run the code in the terminal (in which you can output/input) follow these steps :

1. Go to the Code Runner extension settings
2. Search for "run in terminal" and click in the small square.

Comment: Please do make use of the text formatting options available.

Comment: Do you mean I should use paragraphs or lists to make my answer clearer or someting more involved like colors or images ?

Comment: I've put lists now, is it better or do you have other propositions to make my answer better ?

Comment: @Brooke Jackson I have a problem with thi cmd. When I running it nothing happens, only this line `[Running] cd "c:\git\Cprata\" && gcc test.c -o test && "c:\git\Cprata\"test` apper in OUTPUT ?

Answer (score 0):

There's the `Tasks: Run Build Task` VS Code command, which you can run in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). It is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, but you can rebind it to whatever you want. If you configure a default build task, it will run the default build task. Otherwise, it will open a menu for you to pick one from the available options.

The C/C++ extension should detect what compilers you have installed on your machine and provide generated build tasks in that menu. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652228/11107541.

The CMake Tools extension contributes the commands `CMake: Build` and `CMake: Build Target`. For keybinding, see the command IDs `cmake.build`, `cmake.buildAll`, `cmake.buildWithTarget`, and `cmake.buildNamedTarget`.