# How to add language to visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, customization

I want to be able to use vscode for code golfing in esolangs, but I don't see any way to just simply add a language. I have an interpreter, how can I add it as a language? Everything I've found has either been about changing python interpreters, or integrating autocomplete, eslint, etc. etc. which I don't need for writing brainfuck or golfscript.

I don't want to create a vscode extension just to avoid manually running it with the interpreter from the terminal.

I did get it working by changing the interpreter and extension for a language I do not use, but that is a very stupid solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a language"? You want to execute some command on a keypress? Could be revelant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844962/execute-a-bat-file-on-keypress-in-vscode/59849230#59849230

Comment: All language stuff done by VSC is done with extensions, so if you want something for a new language write an extension.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I want to add a custom language, and assign a file extension and interpreter for that language. You can change and add file extensions and interpreters for existing languages, but there is no way to create a new one(that I know of at least, that is the point of this question).

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "adding a custom language"? "Assigning a file extension" - do you want custom syntax highlighting? Or what? "Assign an interpreter" - VSC has no concept of 'assigned interpreters'.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I open a "helloworld.bf" file in vscode. It recognizes it as brainfuck. I click run, it runs it as brainfuck. <- I want this. I do not know how to do this. I do not know what I am doing, that is why I am asking internet people.

Comment: What do you mean by "click run"? VSC doesn't have that button by default, you must have some extra extensions.